# VIsual Studio 2012-2013 Color Scheme Settings Dialog?

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if there was any way to make the settings dialog match the color scheme of the rest of the program ? I use a darker scheme and when I need to go through settings, it still uses the default white background / black text color scheme. Which is hard on the eyes as it contrasts with the rest of the program. Is there any plugin or otherwise way to make it follow the rest of visual studio's color scheme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. But you are right this is a missing feature.